# So I am kinda lost in my code in Crib Drag Attack(For Educational Purposes)

Tags: python, cryptography

So I am lost on how to make a hexadecimal to ascii code. I am doing this for educational purposes. I am still learning about cryptography and python in general. I do not know the code for decrypting Hex to ASCII. My converting to hex string will have an error and it will not get an input from the user.

```
def crib_drag_attack(guess, cp1, cp2):

xor_ciphers = ""
for idx in range(len(cp1)):
    ic1 = ord(cp1[idx])
    ic2 = ord(cp2[idx])
    ic_xor = ic1 ^ ic2
    xor_ciphers += chr(ic_xor)

for idx in range(len(xor_ciphers) - len(guess)+1):
    slide = xor_ciphers[idx: idx + len(guess)]
    results = ""
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        ig = ord(guess[i])
        id = ord(slide[i])
        ir = ig ^ id
        results += chr(ir)
    print(results)


def encrypt(key, plaintext):
idx = 0  # Declare index (idx) variable
ciphertext = ""  # Declare ciphertext variable
for p in plaintext:  # Take one character at a time in message
    ip = ord(p)  # Convert to Decimal value code
    k = key[idx]  # Take byte value of the key at idx
    ik = ord(k)  # Convert to Decimal value code
    inew = ip ^ ik  # XOR bit-by-bit
    ciphertext += chr(inew)  # Convert to character code and Update ciphertext
    print(p, hex(ip), k, hex(ik), hex(inew))  # print every result
    idx += 1  # Increment idx by 1

hexstring = ciphertext.encode("ascii").hex()
print("\n{} --> {}\n".format(ciphertext, hexstring))

trial = bytes.fromhex(hexstring).decode("ascii")
print("Trial: {}".format(trial))

return ciphertext


def decrypt(key, ciphertext):
idx = 0  # Declare index (idx) variable
plaintext = ""  # Declare plaintext variable
for c in ciphertext:  # Take one character at a time in message
    ic = ord(c)  # Convert to Decimal value code
    k = key[idx]  # Take byte value of the key at idx
    ik = ord(k)  # Convert to Decimal value code
    inew = ic ^ ik  # XOR bit-by-bit
    plaintext += chr(inew)  # Convert to character code and Update ciphertext
    print(c, hex(ic), k, hex(ik), hex(inew))  # print every result
    idx += 1  # Increment idx by 1

print("\n{} --> {}\n".format(plaintext, plaintext.encode("ascii").hex()))
return plaintext


if __name__ == '__main__':

# ciphertext1 = encrypt(key, message1)
# plaintext1 = decrypt(key, ciphertext1)
# #
# ciphertext2 = encrypt(key, message2)
# plaintext1 = decrypt(key, ciphertext2)

# place the given ciphertext 1 and 2 below

#

# Insert the hex string below
ciphertextHex1 = ""
ciphertextHex2 = ""

# Convert the hex string to ascii string
quote_h  = "300d04014"
quote = binascii.a2b_hex("%s" % 
(quote_h.strip())).decode("ASCII").replace(';', '\n- ')
print(quote)

guess = input("Guess a word: ")
crib_drag_attack(guess, ciphertext1, ciphertext2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not so "pythonic". Let's try another way...

Firstly how to properly convert formats from Hex to bytes etc...

The most recommended way to convert hex to bytes is this one:

```py
quote_h  = "0300d04014" # added a zero at the beginning because you give 9 characters and in python, in this situation we just add prefix `0`.
quote = bytes.fromhex(quote_h)
```

Next thing you need to keep in mind...

When dealing with cryptography, it's not recommended to `.decode()` things because `str` does not support all the byte values as like `encoded strings`.

Next thing is a much more pythonic way to xor values...

I want to xor `12345` with your `quote_h` variable:

```py
key = b'12345'.hex() # '3132333435'
quote_h  = "0300d04014"

key = int(key, 16) # From hex to integer | 211295614005
quote = int(quote_h, 16) # From hex to integer | 12898549780

key_xor_quote = key ^ quote # 215602132001

key_xor_quote_h = hex(key_xor_quote)[2:] # From integer to hex without the '0x' prefix | '3232e37421'
# ATTENTION: Be careful here because if the first characters
# in hex format where zeros, then hex() would pass 
# them and the result would be something 
# like this 300d04014 which is invalid because you miss the first zero
# and you will get invalid error in the next command.
# Try to think a way to handle this situation.

key_xor_quote_bytes = bytes.fromhex(key_xor_quote_h) # b'22\xe3t!'
```

Here is exactly what you need to know, good luck on the implementation ;)